# Was there originally a different plan for Meteora and Toffee in Star vs the Forces of Evil?

Tags: star-vs-the-forces-of-evil

In *Star vs. the Forces of Evil*, especially in seasons three and four, a lot of attention is given to Meteora, Queen Eclipsa's daughter. Yet, she plays a minor role during the final episodes.

The same is with Toffee, the bad guy at the end of season three. It is heavily implied he would make an appearance at the end of season four, but aside from a brief cameo, he did not.

So, my question is: Was there originally plans for a different ending in SVTFOE, and if yes, do we have any information (from the shows actors, directors, writers etc) what it was going to be?